# pandas read sql does not return all rows

Tags: pandas, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

for some reason pandas.psql.read_sql does not return all rows

As an example take a look at this query `SELECT count(*) FROM textguard`

query in Datagrip(shows real count):
[image]

The same query in jupyter notebook:

[image]

What might cause this problem? And this problem appears not only with this table or query, but with other tables and queries as well.

For example, when I do a big query with unions from 3 tables it returns me like 90k rows, but when I run all subqueries separately then they give me more than 150k rows (the real amount is over 200k though)

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: @Manakin PostgreSQL 10.12

Comment: it might be you're querying a view rather than the actual table, run a few of the queries mentioned [here](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-tables-used-by-a-view)

Comment: @Manakin I don't think this is my case for a few reasons:  
1) When I print some of the returned rows by read_sql it shows the real data from my table  
2) Why the same query returns 14kk rows in psql console and datagrip then? (If I'm querying view instead of my table then the behavior should be the same among all platforms(psql console, datagrip, jupyter notebook), isn't it?)

Comment: Best guess, you are not connecting to the same instance of Postgres in Jupyter as you are in the other clients.  Verify your connection parameters for all the clients. Alternate theory is you have row level security enabled and the user you are connecting as in Jupyter does not have sufficient privileges to see all rows.

Comment: I'd go with Adrian above... check your connection string.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver you're right guys, my bad, it's been a year since last time I changed this file via jupyter notebook and forgot that remote db's ip was changed